# Updating the contents of a View in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-view

I have a `ListView` which will host compound Views called `TaskView`, which is a visual representation of a `Task`. The background work is done in an `AsyncTask` and the `TaskView`'s children (two `TextView`s and one `ProgressView`) are updated in `onProgressUpdate()`. After I'm finished updating the Views, I call `listView.invalidateViews()`, which I believe is *supposed* to redraw all its child Views. However, this is not the case because none of the views change. After setting some breakpoints and observing the values of the various views, I have determined that they *do* change, but their new values just aren't reflected onscreen

Here is an outline of my `AsyncTask` (note: class and method names have been simplified)

```
private TaskView view;

public Monitor(TaskView view) {
    this.view = view;
}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // <set up a handler to push events to onProgressUpdate()>
    // <do work>
    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Event... values) {
    Task task = view.getTask();

    // <update task based on the Event>

    view.update(); // Tells view to update its TextViews and ProgressBar
                   // based on task's values
    listView.invalidateViews(); // Refresh ListView views?
}
```

How can I get `ListView` to redraw its children?

---

As requested, here is `TaskAdapter.getView()`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Task task = getItem(position);
    TaskView view = (TaskView) convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        // Instantiates a TaskView and sets the Task
        view = TaskView.newInstance(getContext(), task);
    }
    return view;
}
```

and `TaskView.update()`

```
public void update() {
    // https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel
    progressWheel.setProgress(task.getProgress());
    if (task.isIndeterminate()) {
        progressWheel.spin();
    } else {
        progressWheel.stopSpinning();
    }

    // status and secondaryStatus are TextViews
    status.setText(task.getStatus());
    secondaryStatus.setText(task.getSecondaryStatus());
}
```

Comment: Is it updating after scroll? I have same problem like this.....

Comment: @Amsheer It doesn't update after scrolling

Answer (score 3):

To refresh the listview with new data call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of the adapter assigned to the listview.

Comment: from what i've understand from your question you are updating the text of your textview?then this would be the answer.

Comment: The ListView's TaskView's children still remain unchanged.

Comment: He is right. The only thing that you need to change is the data itself and call notifyDataSetChanged() of the list adapter. This method call makes the listview rendered again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `invalidate()` method for each view you've changed.
Another trick is :
updating the array list object that you pass to the adapter for example if the view that you want to update is at position i do this:

```
list.remove(i);
list.add(i, new object()); // the new object must have the updated content 
adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

Update:

let me tell you the problem again:
you have a list with a taskview object ( each row corresponds to a taskview)
in each row you have a progrees bar and 2 textviews
you want to update some rows

Solution :

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Event... values) {
    Task task = view.getTask();

    task.setProgress() // first change the content of taskView data
    task.setStatus()
    task.setSecondaryStatus()

    // now let the adapter do update the rows
    adapter.notifyDataSetChange() // if it dose not work remove task and add to list and then again call notify

 }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = 
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.list_item, parent, false);

    Task task = getItem(position);
    TextView status = view.findViewById();
    status.setText(task.getStatus());
    Progressbar pb = view.findViewById();
    //....

    TextView secondaryStatus = view.findViewById();
    secondaryStatus.setText(task.getSecondaryStatus());
    return view;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: I have tested it on a textview and it has worked, when i clickes a button the textview content changes.

Comment: Still nothing changes.

Comment: But i just tested the two ways and got result, for example i put a button in each list row and when i press it, that row will delete or the textview of that row gets updated. I think you should post getView and view.update() functions.

Comment: This still does not change anything :(

Comment: I think it is time to vote me down but i do not care and want to continue and solve this challenge so let me a little time to think

Comment: Thank you for your dedication! I wasn't the one who downvoted you by the way.

Comment: look at my new answer, people i think write their codes this way and usually it gets result